# Convert ARKit App (UIKit) to VisionOS RealityKit app

Tags: arkit, reality-composer, visionos, reality-composer-pro

Is there a way of integrating the RealityKitContent
[image]

to an app created with Xcode12 using UIKit?

The non AR parts are working ok in VisionOS, the AR parts need to be rewritten in SwiftUI.
In order to be able to do so,I need to access the RealityKit content and be able to work it seamlessly with Reality Composer Pro, but unsure how to integrate RealityKitContent is such pre-SwitftUI/VisionOS project.
I am using Xcode 15

Thank you.